# Changing the value of an attribute depending of the value of a second attribute of the same element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <trans>
       <language type="lang" lang="DE"/>
    </trans>
    <trans>
       <language type="lang" lang="EN"/>
    </trans>
</root>
```

My goal is to replace the value of the attribute "type" depending on the value specified in the "lang" attribute.

This is the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <trans>
       <language type="German" lang="DE"/>
    </trans>
    <trans>
       <language type="English" lang="EN"/>
    </trans>
</root>
```

I have started with the following but don't get any further at this point:

```
   <xsl:template match="language">
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="@lang=DE">
       <xsl:attribute name="type">
         <xsl:value-of select="'German'"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    ???
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. -- How many languages are there overall?

Comment: It is XSLT 2.0 and the number of languages can vary.

Comment: What do you mean "it can vary"? If you want to add a value to each code, you must prepare a list binding codes to values. I am asking how many entries will be in this list.

Comment: It depends on the number of languages needed, in my case it's trilingual (DE, EN, FR). The number of entries is not limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these 3 templates (1st one is an identity template; second will "eat up" all @type; and third one will generate both attributes again, based on the @type):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//language/@type"/>

<xsl:template match="//language/@lang">
  <xsl:attribute name="lang">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="type">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=".='DE'">German</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test=".='EN'">English</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>Other</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was aiming for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:data="data">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <data:languages>
    <lang key="DE" value="German"/>
    <lang key="EN" value="English"/>
  </data:languages>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="language">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name() != 'type']"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="type">
        <xsl:value-of select="document('')//lang[@key = current()/@lang]/@value"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <trans>
    <language lang="DE" type="German" />
  </trans>
  <trans>
    <language lang="EN" type="English" />
  </trans>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only three languages, and you're only using this translation in one place, then `xsl:choose` makes an attractive choice. Of course, it can be implemented much more simply as:

**XSLT 1.0 or 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="language/@type">
    <xsl:attribute name="type">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../@lang='DE'">German</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="../@lang='EN'">English</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="../@lang='FR'">French</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With more languages, and/or if you need to reuse the code in several places, it might be more convenient to switch to a lookup:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="languages">
    <language code="DE">German</language>
    <language code="EN">English</language>
    <language code="FR">French</language>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="lang" match="language" use="@code" />

<xsl:template match="language/@type">
    <xsl:attribute name="type">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('lang', ../@lang, $languages)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```